# High-level language to assembly

Tags: compiler

If assembly language is only a readable way to represent machine code, then why are HLLs converted to assembly first and then to machine code?

Shouldn't HLLs be directly converted to machine code?

Answer (score 3):

This is customary practice on Unix systems because it simplifies the compilers.  Compiling is largely not dependent on the gritty details of machine code, and many compilers can all target the same assembler.

Some compilers target an intermediate abstract machine (like JVM) or even an intermediate concrete machine (MIPS) which is not the actual hardware the code will everntually run on.

Some compilers do go directly to machine code.  It's not very portable and portability is a big thing now (it didn't used to be back in the stone age of computing.)

Comment: "it didn't used to be back in the stone age of computing.": Well C was born as a high-level, portable assembly language, i.e. it was closer to the machine architecture than other languages like Pascal but abstract enough to be portable.

Comment: +1 for "simplifies the compilers" - if you have a perfectly good assembler already, why reinvent the wheel by spitting out binary opcodes from your HLL compiler when it's so much simpler to emit assembly code?

Comment: "on Unix systems" isn't this on *almost all* systems? At least I haven't seem a modern system/compiler where it wasn't the case

Comment: @Giorgio: I disagree with the characterization of C as a "portable assembly language". An assembly language program specifies a particular sequence of machine instructions. A C program specifies run-time behavior. That's a *huge* semantic difference.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: Maybe "portable assembly" is the wrong formulation, but still C is a very thin layer on top of assembly. At least in the first versions of C, most C constructs could be mapped to assembly in a very straightforward way. E.g. the only allowed function return types were types that would fit into a processor register (the 'accumulator' register was often used for this).

Comment: Any machine that uses C as it's system language is too new to be part of the stone age.  In the stone age, system level work was done in assembler.

Comment: Back in the stone age of computing, in particular for darpa so that we could all talk to each other, C and Unix were successful specifically because of portability.  lack of portability back in the stone age of computing (barely after we went digital with transitors) was a huge problem and a big thing then.  has been ever since, microsoft and intel dominate or at least did for a long time specifically because of portability from prior product to present.  companies that didnt could only corner a (relatively) small market share.